# writing text field values to the document in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 function submitValue () {
        var content = $('input[name="foo"]').val();
        $('.teamcolumn').html(content); 

    }


$('#team').submit(submitValue());
```

I have also tried this to submit the button, but neither have worked.

```
$('#team').submit(function() {
    $(this).val()).appendTo('.teamcolumn');
});
```

html:

```
<form>
      <input name="foo" id="team" class="inputright" type="text" value="Team?">
                <input type="submit" value= "Go">
    </form>

<div class="teamcolumn TOSRcolumn"></div>
```

I want to write the value given to me in the text field to the div with the class .wincolumn when a user clicks the submit button. Been playing around with a bunch of different methods but can't seem to figure it out

UPDATED CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(.input[name="foo"]).val();
    $('.teamcolumn').html(value);
    return false;

});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input name="foo" id="team" class="inputright" type="text" value="Team?"></input>
<input type="submit" value"Go"></input
</form>
</body
</html>
```

Comment: div with the class .wincolumn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var value = $('input[name="foo"]').val();
   $('.teamcolumn').html(value);
   $('.wincolumn').html(value);
   return false;
});​
```

[Demo on jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/BwzjK/)

OR

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var value = $('input[name="foo"]').val();
   $('.teamcolumn').html(value);
   $('.wincolumn').html(value);
   return false;
});​
```

[Demo on jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/BwzjK/1/)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks! worked great on jsfiddle but I can't seem to get it working in my browser. the url comes back with the extension of foo="teamthatienter" and nothing is written to the page

Comment: it keeps working on jsfiddle but every time i do it in my browser im getting the same message of foo="textientered" and nothing on the page. any idea why?

Comment: Try shifting your javascript code to some other js file. Then first include your jQuery.js and then include the new js File. Also check if both the files are getting downloaded or not.

Comment: If you don't mind... what if i wanted to just add each new entry to this list? appentTo()? add()?

Comment: Retrieve older value, put it in some temp variable and add new value to it. Or you can check javascript array object. and can use `join` method on it.

Comment: i figured out how to do it with the temp variable. i am going to add more text fields and hopefully make all the value as parameters to an object that gets created when the submit form button is clicked

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8103/discussion-between-nic-meiring-and-amar-palsapure)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submit
    $('.teamcolumn').text($('#team').val());
});
```

Comment: what would i pass as e when i call the function?

Comment: When the submit button is clicked, jQuery will provide the click event information through parameter `e`. You don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're trying to bind the submit handler to the *input*. The input doesn't get submitted; it's the form. Give the form an ID and bind the handler to that, then it'll work (you'll have to prevent the form from submitting though).

Comment: This can be done by doing `$('form').submit(function(e){ });` as I demoed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value= "Go">

function submitValue () {
    var content = $('input[name="foo"]').val();
    $('.teamcolumn').html(content); 

}


$('#submitButton').click(submitValue);
```